# Measurability of a function of a R.V. w.r.t. potential outcomes of that R.V

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, causality

Let $X, Z$ be random variables and $f$ a measurable function. Let $X_{Z=z}$ denote a R.V. that is the counterfactual $X$ we would have seen had $Z$ been set to $z$ (i.e., $Z(\omega) \equiv z, \forall \omega \in \Omega$), leaving all else fixed.
In a proof of some lemma in a paper I'm reading there's a statement that goes:

> If $f(X)$ is $\{X_{Z=z}\}_z$-measurable then ...

My question is: How can $f(X)$ be **NOT** $\{X_{Z=z}\}_z$-measurable since by the *observational consistency* axiom $f(X(\omega)) = f(\sum_z \mathbf{1}_{Z=z}(\omega)X_{Z=z}(\omega)) = \sum_z \mathbf{1}_{Z=z}(\omega)f(X_{Z=z}(\omega))$, where $\mathbf{1}_{X=x}(\omega)$ is the indicator function defined for $\omega \in \Omega$ as:
$$
\begin{equation}
   \mathbf{1}_{X=x}(\omega) = \begin{cases}
      1, & X(\omega) = x \\ 
      0, & X(\omega) \ne x
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$
and by the *existence of potential outcomes* axiom $X_{Z=z}$ exists for all $z \in Z(\Omega)$ (see "[Causal Models on Probability Spaces"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.01672)).

Thank you,
David

Comment: The definition of $X(z)$ is unclear.  A random variable is a function  $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Is $z \in \Omega$?  The concept of "counterfactual $X$ we would have seen had $Z$ been set to $z$" is not clear. Given $Z=z$, there can still be a number of possible values that $X$ can take.  $\{X(\omega) \in \mathbb{R}: \omega \in \Omega, Z(\omega) = z\}$ can be a set that has more than one element.

Comment: @Michael See the edit above for clarification

Comment: Your edit does not clarify things. Please precisely define what is meant by "counterfactual $X$ we would have seen had $Z$ been set to $z$." You likely should specify a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and so on. It seems you are simply defining a constant random variable $Z=z$ surely, and that has no inherent connection to the random variable $X$. [PS: I did not downvote, but I assume the downvoter also viewed the problem as being unclear.]

Comment: @Michael I think the idea is that $X = X(\omega, Z(\omega))$ is thought of as a (random) function of the random variable $Z$, and so $X_{Z=z} = X(\omega,z)$.  Please correct me if I misunderstood.

Comment: @user6247850 : That may be another interesting structure, but I believe the desired question was simpler than what you are suggesting (see my answer below). The notation $X \cdot 1_{\{Z=z\}}$ is something everyone can understand (it is the multiplication of two random variables) while this "counterfactual" description and the $X_{Z=z}$ notation seems a bit hazy.

Comment: @user6247850 Almost ;) This captures the *interventional* 2nd level in Pearl's hierarchy whereas I needed the *counterfactual* 3rd level; see [On Pearl’s Hierarchy and the Foundations of Causal Inference](https://causalai.net/r60.pdf). BTW, IMHO Pearl's method is **much** clearer and formal, but the paper I was studying used the potential outcomes framework. The two are equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$.  Suppose you have two random variables $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $Z:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.  I believe you mean to define a new random variable for each $z\in \mathbb{R}$ by
$$ Y_z = X \cdot 1_{\{Z=z\}} = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
X & \mbox{ if $Z=z$} \\
0 & \mbox{ else} 
\end{array}\right.$$
Then I think you are asing if $X$ is always $\sigma(\{Y_z\}_{z \in \mathbb{R}})$-measurable.   The answer is no.

---

A case where it is true: It is true if $Z$ can take only a finite or countably infinite number of values:  Define $S=\{Z(\omega) \in \mathbb{R}: \omega \in \Omega\}$.  If $S$ is finite or countably infinite then indeed we have
$$ X = \sum_{z \in S} Y_z$$
and so $X$ is $\sigma(\{Y_z\}_{z \in \mathbb{R}})$-measurable.

---

A case where it is not true is this: Let $X \in \{-1,1\}$ equally likely.  Let $Z$ be independent of $X$ and suppose $Z$ has a continuous CDF (such as a $N(0,1)$ distribution).  It can be shown that $X$ is $\sigma(\{Y_z\}_{z \in \mathbb{R}})$-measurable if and only if $X$ is a measurable function of a countably infinite number of the $Y_z$ variables. But for any countably infinite set of real numbers $\{z_1, z_2, z_3, ...\}$, we have
$$P[\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}\{Y_{z_i}=0\}]=1$$
So, with prob 1, we obtain no useful information from the $Y_{z_i}$ variables and we cannot obtain $X$ from $(Y_{z_1}, Y_{z_2}, Y_{z_3}, ...)$.  So $X$ is not $\sigma(\{Y_z\}_{z \in \mathbb{R}})$-measurable. For the same reason, $Z$ is not $\sigma(\{Y_z\}_{z \in \mathbb{R}})$-measurable.

Comment: Thank you for the example. This is indeed what I had in mind (except for calling your $Y_z$ $X_z$ or $X_{Z=z}$.   
How would your answer change if Z is *not* independent of X (e.g., Z is a parent of X in the causal graph $Z \rightarrow X$)?

Comment: As I had mentioned, that same example has $Z$ is not $\sigma(\{Y_z\}_{z \in \mathbb{R}})$ measurable. So we could redefine $X$ by $X=Z$.

Comment: Thank you. Now it's clear.  
I tried to upvote your answer, but I'm missing reputation for this to count :(. Sorry

Comment: @qwer1304 : Thanks.  I upvoted your question itself to bring you back up to 0 reputation. =)  I think the downvoter did not think the description was clear (I was also confused about the "counterfactual" business).

Comment: Thank you.  BTW, could you point me to where "It can be shown that X is σ({Yz}z∈R)-measurable if and only if X is a measurable function of a countably infinite number of the Yz variables." is shown? Thx

Comment: Related statements are in Exercise 1.1.22 in [DEMBO, A. (2013). Probability Theory: STAT 310 notes] and Section 3.13d in [WILLIAMS, D. (1991). Probability with Martingales]. The main idea is to show that $\sigma(\{Y_z\}_{z\in \mathbb{R}})$ includes all sets in the sigma algebra generated by $Y_{z_1}, Y_{z_2}, Y_{z_3},...$  for any countable sequence $\{z_i\}$, and yet that set is also a sigma algebra, so it must be the same as $\sigma(\{Y_z\}_{z\in \mathbb{R}})$.  I recently used this fact in an arxiv paper here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.02345

Comment: Thank you very much.